# Yii Boilerplate where to unzip files

Tags: php, yii, boilerplate

I'be been trying to find the answer to this but no luck. 
Should all zip be unzipped to the www directory? That would be weird as the url to the sites would look like `localhost/myapp/frontend/`. It would be much better to have links like `localhost/myapp/` Also - putting all files (including yii framework files) seems kind of not secure.

Answer (score 0):

You may specify your `localhost` directory by editing the file `000-default` in `etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Edit these lines:

```
[4]DocumentRoot /var/www
[9]<Directory /var/www/>
```

For example, if your `myapp` is in `www/myapp`, then you'd navigate to the page: `localhost/myapp`

Comment: Not sure if it solves the problem. If I change `localhost` directory - it will point to one project and there are more of them at the server.
My root is now `/var/www/yiiboilerplate/xxx` where `xxx` is `frontend` or `backend`. But beside `yiiboilerplate` app - there are different apps to.

Comment: For that, you `must` put all your projects in the same localhost directory.